# how to fit the size of text inside button in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

in unity, when i put button inside the canvas,, then i want to write on it so i add a text  then i will have this problem as in picture:
the text was very very large and if i try to make its size as button ,, the work will be as bluried 
i attach the scene view and game view

[scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xxUS.png)
[game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8naqq.png)

Comment: Post a screenshot of your `Text` component in the Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text object is a child of the button. Try to reset the transform of the text object.